# Why does Pycharm give a non project file warning for project source files on network drive

Tags: pycharm, nas

I have a python project folder on a network drive.  When debugging in PyCharm I get the "Non Project File" warning each time I try to edit a file after reaching a breakpoint.  The files are all in the project folder, which is marked as a source.

I think it has something to with the mapping of the nextwork drive, and PyCharm reading this incorrectly/inconsistently. When I open the project Pycharm correctly reads the address as (the mapped) X:\Project_folder.  However, when it is debugging it loses the mapping address and shows the module address as {server_name}{server_drive_name}\Project_Folder\Module, i.e. not X\Project_Folder\Module, and hence appears to think it is a non project folder.

I have tried the following, none of which have fixed the problem:

- Rebuild the entire project
- Adjust the script path and working directory in the Run Configuration to the server (not mapped) address
- Placed modules in a folder explicitly marked Sources (in Settings>Project Structure).

Is this a bug in pycharm?  Or is there something I can do to fix this?  Any help would be enormously appreciated, as it's driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm may give a "non-project file warning" for project source files on a network drive because these files may have slower access times compared to local files. This can cause performance issues when working with large projects in PyCharm, since the IDE needs to read and write to these files frequently.

Additionally, network drives can also be subject to network connectivity issues, which can cause additional latency and errors when working with files stored on them.

To avoid these issues, it's recommended to store your PyCharm projects on a local drive. If you must use a network drive, you can try to improve the performance by using a fast network connection and a fast storage solution on the network drive.